# What should be in a coding standard?

Tags: coding-standards

What should be in a good (read:useful) coding standard?

- Things the code should have.
- Things the code shouldn't have.
- Should the coding standard include definitions of things the language, compiler, or code formatter enforces?
- What about metrics like cyclomatic complexity, lines per file, etc?

Comment: See Also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/what-parts-of-your-coding-standard-contribute-to-quality-code

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A reasons for every requirement.  This way, following the standard doesn't become some sort of cargo cult and people know that it's ok to change the standard if the reason for it no longer applies, or to violate the standard in specific cases where the reason clearly doesn't apply.

Comment: Absolutely.  Every item in a standard should have the rationale specified explicitly.

Comment: Sometimes there is no good reason for a choice, but it's desirable to have everybody do the same.  I don't know why we all drive on the right, to use a car analogy, but it's much better than half on the right and half on the left.

Comment: @David:  That's a perfectly legitimate reason for having a coding standard.  If that's the reason then it should simply be stated as such, i.e. "Reason:  To improve consistency of the codebase."

Comment: In fact, the most important thing about a coding standard is that there *is* one. *What* is in there is really secondary.

Answer (score 20):

Tabs vs Spaces!
I get crazy updates when one of my colleagues accidentally commits a lot of tabs to spaces shift into the repository

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly!

Comment: IMHO, that's **an only** thing that deserves being in a coding standard.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaceswhat-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-ev

Comment: IMHO, that is a excellent example of what a coding standard _should not_ cover.

Comment: @bjarkef, you prefer mixed tab & spaces code?

Comment: @Xepoch - the point is that tab v space is a triviality. What is important and should go in the standard is words along the lines of "you will not fuck up the code history with changes for no reason - eg changing whitespace". This applies to bracket position and everything else. If code is mixed tab and space, so what - you may prefer all spaces, but tough. Unless you change something else on that line, you must leave that whitespace alone.

Comment: Tabs vs. spaces, as well as a lot of other code formatting stuff, can be handled automagically at checkin, and should be so handled if your firm mandates it in the first place.

Answer (score 19):

Naming Conventions

**EDIT:** By this I mean naming Guidelines, not naming Rules.

For example, a Guideline would be `All boolean values should begin with Is/Can/Has/etc when possible`. A rule would be `All boolean values must start with Is`

Comment: LPSZ* lppsz_CPP_MrKim_ClassOfStudents[][];

Comment: -1: This is exactly the sort of low-level detail that causes developers to ignore standards.  You might as well mandate that everyone wear neckties.

Comment: @TMN:  Lack of naming conventions are the exact sort of thing that causes developers to despair of ever understanding the code.  They don't have to be nit-picky, but a few general guidelines will help immensely.

Comment: The last large project I worked on had naming conventions.  One was that any non-primitive-type variable have its name prefixed with "obj".  This was for a Java project, so 95%+ of the variables were objects of some sort.  The convention that arose was to simply have all variables be "obj" + the class name.  So we wound up with lots of variables with names like "objAddress" and "objCompany".  I've never seen a naming convention that added any value to the code.

Comment: @TMN: Sounds like a bad naming standard to me. I am not referring to a detailed naming standard such as how to name each variable type, but I would like to see some generic guidelines  for how to name your items. Stuff like All public properties/methods should be capitalized, boolean values should begin with Is/Can/Has/etc if possible, private variables are camelCase, etc. It drives me crazy to go through someone else's code and find that they don't capitalize items in a consistent manner, or that I can't identify a variable/method is without going to its definition

Comment: @Rachel: Yeah, we had the "all boolean properties must start with 'Is'" standard.  Wound up with properties like `IsCanUpdate` and `IsHasChildren`.  Sure, it's wrong, but it was decreed in the standard.  And this is my point: once you start specifying these things, you have to make sure you cover all the bases, or else people run into something the standard doesn't cover, or covers badly, and then they either write something that's wrong, or they start ignoring the standard.  Either way, the team loses.

Comment: That's why I think it should include Guidelines, not Rules, for how to name your objects. Exact names are still left up to the developers. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: +1 for guidelines, not rules.

Answer (score 10):

A coding standard for a group should include the **compiler options for warnings and errors** that must be addressed.

Programmers should be free to *increase* warnings for their own code, but there must be a baseline so that reading and working with someone else's code doesn't clutter up the output you get from the compiler.

Such a standard would also have to address how programmers can disable such warnings case-by-case, should there be an exceptional piece of code that won't otherwise conform.

Comment: Agreed. The other part I'd add is that if you're leaving it alive as a warning, then it must be addressed by changing it or suppressing the warning. Otherwise, warnings get to be useless fast (too many in a large project) and you may as well shut them off. In VS, I prefer to see Warnings break the build and force you to deal with them.

Comment: Isn't this something you should put in your makefile and not in a standard?

Comment: @bjarkef: Ultimately the **options** will go into the Makefile, yes. But the point of putting it into the standard is to standardize what must be addressed. For example, should developers always create serialization IDs? It's up to the team to decide if this should be mandated or ignored.

Comment: @bjarkef: Sure, but it's good to have them in a standard reference for when you start a new project and have to write a new makefile (or your new project uses something other than Make for its build tool).

Answer (score 9):

Some standards I like (I know there is a lot of them, but that's those I prefer):

- 80% unit tests coverage
- Collective ownership of the code (write code to be read by your team mates, not the compiler)
- Write comments. Write what you would say to a newcomer.
- Keep it simple

Comment: Requirements concerning unit test coverage is one of the very best things that can go into coding standards.

Comment: Regarding test coverage: Why only 80%? Is this an example of the 80/20 rule again, where in your experience that final 20% would take 100% more effort to achieve? Also, what kind of coverage? [e.g. Statement coverage? Function coverage? Decision coverage? Condition coverage?]

Comment: @Macneil: yes something like that. I found that 80% is "good enought" for most classes and is a good number. I've once tried to achieve 95% and it was a real waste of time. Of course if it's easy to achieve 100% for some classes, go ahead

Comment: So is that statement coverage? It seems many tools don't give you more than that. What tool do you use?

Comment: I use TestDriven.net with built it nCover

Comment: A nice alternative rule is `CC-after-change >= CC-before-change`. That way, you don't have to pick an arbitrary threshold *and* you are guaranteed to get better (technically, not to get worse) over time.

Comment: 80% is often used because of the difficulty of testing error-handling code.

Comment: @Jorg: thus if I had a branch for a 'just in case this is empty later on', I cannot commit ? Your approach is interesting, but past a certain treshold it's good enough.

Answer (score 7):

Coding Standards help a little when you are writing the code the first time, they help a *lot*  when you, or your replacement, has to update the code 2 years later.

The ideal standard leads to code where you can jump to any arbitrary page in the code, and understand excactly what it is doing on the first read-through, because

- the names clearly describe what data is being manipulated,
- the braces make the flow of control clear,
- the comments explain any non-obvious algorithm, etc.

On the other hand, too many arbitrary standards can disrupt the flow of writing code. So I believe that every item in a proposed coding convention should be evaluated against these 2 criteria:

- Does this rule help ensure that the code is **Correct**?
- Does this rule help ensure that the code is **Clear**?

If neither is true, the item is just arbitrary, and probably unnecessary

---

I would include the following things in a standard I write:

For Clarity:

- File Organization:   Specifying a fixed order for the items in a file lets the team easily navigate others files.   You shouldn't have to hunt to find #defines, or structure definitions.
- Naming conventions:  Consistent naming aids readability.  But avoid over-specifying too many rules, that harms writeability.
- Code Structure.  Curly Brace placement, indentation levels, spaces vs tabs, etc.   Yes, this can be a strong personal preference, but the goal is clear code.  Find the best option for the team, and stick with it.

For Correctness:

- Best Practices specific to your problem type:   Rules about memory allocation, or concurrency, or portability.
- "Const Correctnesss", proper use of `static` and `volatile`, etc.
- Rules about preprocessor macros, and other easily abused features of the language.

Answer (score 6):

Inspiring, pragmatic ideas that make people think, rather than negative restrictions which stop people thinking.

Otherwise, you get code monkeys who are afraid to go after the [bananas](http://creativestudios.com/monkey-spray/).

Answer (score 4):

What should be in a coding standard?   As little as possible.  Less rather more.  And with justification, please.

Not because I'm some cowboy coder who wants no process, but because I've seen heavy coding specs with no logic behind it beyond (presumably) "I found this on the 'Net somewhere back in '95" that just end up becoming a bureaucratic nightmare to work with.

Some people honestly seem to believe that by cranking up the standards they will see a corresponding increase in code "quality" and perhaps by that measure they will.  In the meantime they'll ignore architecture, performance, common sense and a bunch other things that end up mattering more than the number of lines in a file.

Answer (score 3):

A procedure for code reviews to enforce the standard.  Oh, and to find bugs too.

Answer (score 3):

Some good old common sense wouldn’t go amiss; there are far too many coding standard documents that labour on irrelevant points (items such as font type and size being one of the more extreme ones I’ve seen).

The best thing to do if you’re in a group of developers is to talk to each other and look at your code, form a consensus on what is acceptable and if you need to write down the main points as guidelines, but keep them as just that guidelines. If you can’t justify any divergence from the guidelines you really should consider why you’re doing it.

At the end of the day clear and understandable code is more important than any rigid rule on layout or typography.

Comment: How does font type and size get checked?

Comment: @xepoch, it was visually at that point. The reason for it being in the standard of that time was twofold, It was easier for the manager at the time to read when it was printed out and the typeface was specifed to fix the spacing issues (monospace was demanded) so each column of characters lined up.

Comment: oh lord - reminds me of the std that mandated the number of empty lines between everything - between methods I'm happy with (as lots of whitespace helps to differentiate big blocks) but before and after every comment block, and after the fn declaration but before the function code, etc... got a bit silly in the end.

Answer (score 2):

I like the format in the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321545613) it includes a general section and  rationals for the guidelines. The most useful bit are the details which start with Do, Do Not, Avoid and Consider.

Here's an example in the section [Implementing Interface Members Explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229034.aspx) it has the following items (note I dropped the rationales for bervity's sake)

> **Avoid** implementing interface members
>   explicitly without having a strong
>   reason to do so
>
> **Consider** implementing interface members explicitly if the members are intended to be called only through the interface.
>
> **Do not** use explicit members as a security boundary.
>
> **Do** provide a protected virtual member that offers the same functionality as the > explicitly implemented member if the functionality is meant to be specialized by derived classes.

This creates a good general tone. By using Avoid and Consider you can allow for developers to use their judgement. Also because they're guidelines and not rules developers are likely to  find them more palatable and in turn more likely to follow them.

Comment: Where I am currently working all interfaces have to be implemented explicitly and it is a big pain. If only they had read the Framework Design Guidelines before writing their coding standard.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, code test coverage is important.  I also like to see:

- Project structure.  Are the tests part of the code, or are they in a separate project/package/directory?  Does the UI code live with the back-end stuff?  If not, how is it compartmentalized?
- Development process.  Write tests before code?  Does fixing broken builds take priority over development? When are code reviews done, and what should they cover?
- Source code management.  What gets checked in when?  Are design docs and test plans revision-controlled?  When do you branch and when do you tag?  Do you keep previous builds, and if so how many/for how long?
- Deployment standards.  How is a build packaged?  What needs to go into release notes?  How are upgrade scripts created/controlled/run?

Forget all that crap about naming conventions, formatting and how many lines can be in a function/method/module.  One rule: use whatever the existing style is in whatever it is you're editing.  If you don't like somebody's style, pick it apart in a code review.  The only exception might be the tabs-vs-spaces thing, if only because many editors/IDEs will blindly convert one to the other, and then you wind up destroying your change history because every line was changed.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are actually two things to address, and I would in fact consider them separately because they cannot be approached in the same manner, though I find both important.

- The technical aspect: which aims at avoiding risky or ill-formed code (even if accepted by the compiler/interpreter)
- The presentation aspect: which concerns itself with making the program clear to readers

The technical aspect I qualify of *Coding Standard*, as do **Herb Sutter** and **Andrei Alexandrescu** with their *C++ Coding Standards*. The presentation I qualify of *Coding Style*, which includes naming convention, indentation, etc...

**Coding Standard**

Because it is purely technical, a Coding Standard can be mostly objective. As such every rule should be supported by a reason. In the book I referred to each item has:

- A title, simple and to the point
- A summary, which explains the title
- A discussion, which illustrate the issue of doing otherwise and thus states the **rationale**
- *optional* Some examples, because a good example is worth a thousand words
- *optional* A list of exceptions for which this rule cannot be applied, sometimes with work arounds
- A list of references (other books, websites) that have discussed this point

Rationale and Exceptions are very important, as they summarize the why and when.

The title shall be explicit enough that during reviews one only need to have a list of titles (cheat sheet) to work with. And obviously, group the items by category to make it easier to look out for one.

Sutter and Alexandrescu managed to have a list of only a hundred items, even though C++ is deemed hairy ;)

**Coding Style**

This part is generally less objective (and can be downright subjective). The intent here is to guarantee consistency, because this helps maintainers and new comers.

You do not want to enter a holy-war about which indentation or brace style is better here, there are forums for this: so in this category you do things by consensus > majority vote > arbitrary decision by leader(s).

For an example of formatting, see the list of options of [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html). Ideally, the rules should be clear and complete enough that a program could rewrite the code (though it's unlikely you'll ever code one ;) )

For the naming convention, I would try to make class/types easily distinguished from variables/attributes.

It is also in this category that I classify the "measures" like:

- prefer short to long methods: it's usually difficult to agree on what long is
- prefer early return/continue/break to reduce indentation

*Misc ?*

And as a final word, there is one item that is rarely, if ever, discussed in Coding Standards, perhaps because it's particular to each application: code organization. The architectural issue is perhaps the most outstanding issue, screw up on the initial design and you'll be plagued by it years from now. You should perhaps add a section for basic file handling: public/private headers, dependency management, separation of concern, interfacing with other systems or libraries...

---

But those are *nothing* if they are not actually applied and **enforced**.

Any violation should be brought up during code reviews, and no code review should be okay if a violation is outstanding:

- fix the code to match the rule
- fix the rule so that the code doesn't stand out any longer

Obviously, changing a rule means getting the "go ahead" from the leaders.

Answer (score 1):

No one seems to have mentioned security - in a coding standard you must have reference to secure code requirements (eg the use of input validation modules, disallowing known weak functions such as strcpy, error handling requirements etc)

Comment: +1: This and multithreading considerations are often unknown or misunderstood, even by experienced developers.

Answer (score 1):

**Examples.** Neatly arranged, non-trivial, close-to-real-world examples that make use of every rule. Comments (not necessarily part of the code) which part of the example follows which rule.

**Templates.** Not the C++ kind, but something to copy-paste and fill with live. It's much easier to get that 24-lines boilerplate comment right when you have a reference to copy from.

Answer (score 1):

**Number one feature: An absolute maximum of two pages.**

This is something you want every developer to read and remember. You should not have to look up in the standard every time you need to write a new function (or worse a new line). So, keep it short and keep only the rules that really provides increased value to the final product.

Answer (score 1):

Coding standards is really several items:

**Coding conventions**

- these things don't need a reason other then "consistency of code base"
  for ex. to use '_' in private member variables or not.
- there could be several correct approaches. Just need to pick one for consistency.
  for ex. handling errors using exceptions or error codes.

**Best Practices**

- these items always need a good reason with some clear examples

for ex. 
**Never leave empty Catch after try**

`try { Foo(); } catch { //do nothing }`

1) If there is an exception thrown by Foo() it may cause other issues on functions that follow, that assumed that foo was successful.

2) Global error handler will not notify support team of exception when it happens on prod

- covers the practices of "Defensive Coding", like using Asserts to test your assumptions.

**Coding Environment**

- tools that the whole team uses. 
  for ex. VS 2010, Resharper, Kiln, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Coding standards, when written on paper, is only so much effective.  I like it how Go is publishing its coding standard.  It has the tool `gofmt` to format the program text to a format.  Any debate on the coding format then will simply result as a patch to the sources of `gofmt`.

As for what the format should have,

- how to name variables, macros, constants, literals, functions, etc
- how to places {,},(,),[,] when it comes to `if`, function body, statement blocks for any other purposes,
- how wide should indentations be,
- how many characters a line of text is allowed
- how many levels of indentations are allowed before the code is rejected/sent for refactoring
- how many lines of code is allowed per function before it is sent back for refactoring
- maximum number of arguments a function can take before it is sent back for refactoring
- A few lines of comments before a function begins explaining briefly what it does, if the body is to exceed one page of on screen code; leaving how the object is achieved to the code in the function's body

When I am reading others' (C language mostly) code, if variable/function names are not intuitive in the context of the project or if it exceeds five levels of indentation or functions take more than six or seven arguments or a function runs for over two or three pages on screen, it becomes very hard to read and understand the code.  When asked to do enhancements/maintenance work on it, it only adds to the difficulty.  It makes me wish `gofmt` like program be written for every project (or even language) and every source code file be run through that program before it gets committed into the project.

Comment: there's been code beautifiers around for years. Google one for your language, you'll find one.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml).

Its concise in its guidelines yet has details if you need them.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Answer (score -1):

Self documenting code (comments, variable names, function names, etc.)